# How to extract field before a conditional row

Tags: r

```
set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame(
  group = rep(1:3, each = 3),
  year = c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2002", "2003","2004", "2001", "2002", "2004"),
  value = sample(1:9, r = T))
```

How would I extract the previous row if the year is "2003" for the last row within the same group?

For example:

```
group year value
1     2001  4
1     2002  1
1     2003  7
```

For this group since the last row for group 1 the year is 2003, I would extract the previous row. However, if the year in the last row is not 2003, it would just be left out.

Answer (score 2):

An option is

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(lead(year == 2003 & row_number()== n()))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   group [1]
#  group year  value
#  <int> <fct> <int>
#1     1 2002      3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option...

```r
d <- data.frame(group = rep(1:3, each = 3),
  year = c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2002", "2003","2004", "2001", "2002", "2004"),
  value = sample(1:9, r = T),
  stringsAsFactors = F)

d %>% arrange(group,year) %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(year!=2003) %>% slice(n()) %>% filter(year<2003)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   group [1]
  group year  value
  <int> <chr> <int>
1     1 2002      9
```

Which will only return the value for group 1, since groups 2 and 3 have 2004 as the last row, so they should be left out.